# Flatten crumpled papers

Tags: stationery

There are some instances where my important documents get creases when folding and they get crushed accidentally. **How do I remove the creases from these papers?**

NOTE: The papers are not blank. They are either printed or hand written with ink. I have tried to add moisture/mist to the paper and then give it a mild iron, but there are some risks involved in this that ink may get smudged if there is excess moisture.